# Ошибка при запросе к модулю requests

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Я сделал небольшой код для получения музыки с сайта, но у меня появляется ошибка я не знаю как её решить помогите пожалуйста.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from save import save

def get_music(all_music_href,headers):
    all_music_name = all_music_href[1]
    del all_music_name[0]
    i = 0

    for url in all_music_href:
        print(f"Начал скачивать {i+1} из {len(all_music_href)}")
        req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        src = req.text

        save(src)

def get_music_href(url,headers):
    all_music_href = []
    all_music_name = []
    req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")
    all_href = soup.find_all("li", class_="play")
    all_name = soup.find_all("span", class_="track")

    for item in all_href:
        music_href = item.get("data-url")
        all_music_href.append(music_href)

    for item in all_name:
        all_music_name.append(item.text)

    return all_music_href , all_music_name
    
def main():
    headers = {
        "accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"     
    }
    url = r"https://muzofond.fm/collections/diskoteka/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%2080"
    get_music(get_music_href(url,headers),headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**save** это модуль для сохранения в файл, я его на писал для автоматизации этого процесса, и он точно работает.
А вот код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Папка Димы\python\parsing\music 90\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Папка Димы\python\parsing\music 90\main.py", line 40, in main
    get_music(get_music_href(url,headers),headers)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Папка Димы\python\parsing\music 90\main.py", line 12, in get_music
    req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjUyLzM5OS80NjUyMzk5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjcxLzQ4NS80NjcxNDg1Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjU4LzUyNS80NjU4NTI1Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjgyLzEwMS80NjgyMTAxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjU1Lzc1NC80NjU1NzU0Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjc5LzU0NS80Njc5NTQ1Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjgyLzEwMC80NjgyMTAwLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjc1LzU5Ny80Njc1NTk3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjgzLzI0OS80NjgzMjQ5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjgwLzUzNC80NjgwNTM0Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNTg0LzEzNi80NTg0MTM2Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNTg0LzEzNC80NTg0MTM0Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNTg0LzEzNy80NTg0MTM3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNTg0LzEzNS80NTg0MTM1Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNTg0LzEzMi80NTg0MTMyLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNTg0LzEzMS80NTg0MTMxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNTg0LzEzMC80NTg0MTMwLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNTg0LzEyOS80NTg0MTI5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvOTgyLzQ3My8xOTgyNDczLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMjUzLzQzMy8yMjUzNDMzLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNjE1LzcyOS82MTU3MjkubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvNzI3Lzk1Ni8yNzI3OTU2Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvNjQ1LzE5OS8yNjQ1MTk5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvODUyLzgzNy8yODUyODM3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMDAxLzg1OC8xODU4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNTM0LzE1NC8xNTM0MTU0Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvOTk0LzM0My8yOTk0MzQzLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMjMzLzcxMi8yMjMzNzEyLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNzYwLzg2MC83NjA4NjAubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvODQzLzg3Mi8xODQzODcyLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTUyLzIyNC8yMTUyMjI0Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMjM0Lzk0Ny8yMjM0OTQ3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvODQ1LzAzNy8xODQ1MDM3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTUzLzcxMy8yMTUzNzEzLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMjMyLzIyMi8yMjMyMjIyLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMTIwLzExNS8xMjAxMTUubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNTU5LzQ3NC81NTk0NzQubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNjE1LzIzOC82MTUyMzgubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNzM3LzIyMS8xNzM3MjIxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTUyLzIwNy8yMTUyMjA3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTUyLzkzMy8yMTUyOTMzLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTU0LzM0OS8yMTU0MzQ5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTg3LzMxMi8yMTg3MzEyLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTUyLzQxOC8yMTUyNDE4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMDE4LzQ4OC8yMDE4NDg4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMzQyLzE0NC8yMzQyMTQ0Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNzc5Lzc5Ni83Nzk3OTYubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvOTk4LzI0OC85OTgyNDgubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNDMzLzYyNy8xNDMzNjI3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvOTc5LzY0NC8xOTc5NjQ0Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNzk1LzI1MS8xNzk1MjUxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNDI2LzMyMC8xNDI2MzIwLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNzM1LzcwMi8xNzM1NzAyLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTUzLzQ4NS8yMTUzNDg1Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTU2LzYyMi8yMTU2NjIyLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMDAzLzc2OS8yMDAzNzY5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMTE3LzU3Ny8xMTc1NzcubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTU3LzE3My8yMTU3MTczLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvOTEyLzE1OC8xOTEyMTU4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTg3LzYwMy8yMTg3NjAzLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMjQzLzg2NC8yNDM4NjQubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMDUwLzkzNS81MDkzNS5tcDM=', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNzM2LzkyMy83MzY5MjMubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvODk5LzM5MS84OTkzOTEubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvODU4LzI4NS8xODU4Mjg1Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvOTUyLzIxOS8xOTUyMjE5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMjAzLzIyOS8yMjAzMjI5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMjA0LzA5MS8yMjA0MDkxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNTQ4Lzg3MC81NDg4NzAubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTUyLzcxNC8yMTUyNzE0Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNTczLzc4NC81NzM3ODQubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNjY3LzY5OC82Njc2OTgubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTY5LzA2Ny8yMTY5MDY3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNDQ4Lzk0Ni8xNDQ4OTQ2Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNzE3LzQ1Ny83MTc0NTcubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNzQzLzc0OS83NDM3NDkubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNzQ2LzQ0MC83NDY0NDAubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvODU4LzI5OC8xODU4Mjk4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNTgzLzc2OC8xNTgzNzY4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTUzLzI0Ni8yMTUzMjQ2Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTg4LzA0MS8yMTg4MDQxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTcxLzgzMy8yMTcxODMzLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMzg2LzUxMi8yMzg2NTEyLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMDA4LzI3MS84MjcxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMDA5LzgxMy85ODEzLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMTA5LzEzNi8xMDkxMzYubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNjQ5LzQ5NS82NDk0OTUubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMzczLzUwMy8zNzM1MDMubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNzUzLzAxMy83NTMwMTMubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNjE3LzU2My82MTc1NjMubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNzk2LzA5MC83OTYwOTAubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvODc1LzMyNC84NzUzMjQubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvMzA0LzM3Ni8xMzA0Mzc2Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNTM3LzMzNi8xNTM3MzM2Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvOTE4LzU0MS8xOTE4NTQxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvNjE4LzcxMS8yNjE4NzExLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvNjc5LzIxNi8yNjc5MjE2Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvMTMzLzY1Ni8xMzM2NTYubXAz', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvMzY4Lzc3NS8xMzY4Nzc1Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNDM1LzU1OS8xNDM1NTU5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNDY2LzM2OC8xNDY2MzY4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNjg2LzYwNy8xNjg2NjA3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvNzE0LzUzOC8xNzE0NTM4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvODIwLzU1OC8xODIwNTU4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDEvOTE5LzI0Ny8xOTE5MjQ3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMTU5LzY0OC8yMTU5NjQ4Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvMzY2LzkwNy8yMzY2OTA3Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvNjc5LzE3MS8yNjc5MTcxLm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDIvNjc5LzE5NS8yNjc5MTk1Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDAvNjI2LzIxMi82MjYyMTIubXAz']"
```

Извините за беспокойство. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ключ к ответу в последней строке исключения:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL2YubXAzcG9pc2submV0L21wMy8wMDQvNjUyLzM5OS80NjUyMzk5Lm1wMw==', 'https://dl3s2.muzofond.fm/aHR0cDovL <<<snip>>>
```

**requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema** обычно генерируется при неправильно сформатированном url.

Посмотрев на код:

Функция `get_music_href` возвращает `tuple` из двух списков:

```
(<список all_music_href>, <список all_music_name>)
```

Это значение передаётся в функцию `get_music`. В цикле:

```
for url in all_music_href:
```

url получает значение первого элемента `tuple`, т.е. список ссылок вместо ссылки.

Попробуйте, зменить на `for url in all_music_href[0]:`

```
     for url in all_music_href[0]:
            print(f"Начал скачивать {i+1} из {len(all_music_href)}")
            req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
            src = req.text
```

Comment: Я видимо заработался и не заметил этой оплошности. Спасибо вам большое, теперь всё работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста :-) !